# Out of Memory when writing object to file in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm having some trouble with my current project. Hope somebody could help.

In my project, I have to load data from the DB and save to a HashMap and process it(there are about 5 millions of records).

It works quite fine. And for some small tweak, I've decided to save this HashMap object to file, and hope this will save me some time when I have to re-run this program.

And the problem appears when I'm writing that HashMap to file. It runs out of memory.

```
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename"));
 out.writeObject(hashMap);
 out.flush();
 out.close();
```

My question is

1. What can I do solve this problem?
2. What makes it run out of memory when saving object, cause that when I'm processing this HashMap it is fine and when saving object it need not extra memory(Am I wrong).

(I'm developing it in my Eclipse and test it by *Run as java app* in Eclipse)

**Update stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.growEntries(ObjectOutputStream.java:2331)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectOutputStream.java:2256)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1412)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
```

My disk space was around 8GB and I think it is not the problem.

Any suggestion are welcome!
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: How many objects do your `HashMap` contain?

Comment: I hope your disk has enough space? Or you getting java permSpace memory error?

Comment: It may or may not save you any time at all. More to the point, is it really acceptable to process possibly stale data?

Comment: I have updated stack trace.
@EJP I have thought about it and creating that HashMap is complicate.
Accessing to the DB and to file, I prefers the latter for performance(I'm not so sure).

Answer (score 1):

You can always try increasing the java heap space using java -Xmx flag. For example, run your program as `java -Xmx2G`. In Eclipse you can go Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments and type -Xmx2G in the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
Increase your heap memory:

It is possible to increase heap size allocated by the JVM in eclipse directly In eclipse IDE goto

Run---->Run Configurations---->Arguments

Enter -Xmx1g(It is used to set the max size like Xmx256m or Xmx1g...... m-->mb g--->gb)
```